# how to create payment source to be used with stripe subscription with invoice

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, subscription

I need to create a subscription in stripe where customers pay using invoices the receive to go to payment page
so i dont have a customer card details which is required when i try to create a payment source for customer
this is what i did

```
def createStripeCustomer(profile,request):
    host=request.build_absolute_uri()
    parts=host.split('/')
    host=parts[0]+'//'+parts[2]
    source=stripe.Source.create(
        type='card',
        currency='gbp',
        redirect={'return_url':host + '/payments/success/'},
        owner={
            'email': profile.user.email
        }
        )
    customer=stripe.Customer.create(
            description="My First Test Customer ",
            email=profile.user.email,
            name=profile.full_name,
            phone=profile.phone_no,
            address={'line1':profile.address},

            )
    source = stripe.Customer.create_source(
        customer.id,
        source=source.id
        )
    profile.stripe_customer=customer.id
    profile.stripe_source=source.id

    profile.save()
```

and for subscription

```
def createStripeSubscription(subscription):
    price=subscription.course.get_pay_price()
    stripe_price=stripe.Price.create(
            unit_amount=price,
            currency=subscription.course.currency,
            recurring={"interval": "week"},
            product=subscription.course.stripe_product,
            )
    stripe_subscription=stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=subscription.student.stripe_customer,
            items=[
                {"price": stripe_price.id,
                  'quantity': 1,
                  },
                
            ],
            metadata={
                    "subscription_pk": subscription.pk
                },
            )

    subscription.stripe_price=stripe_price.id
    subscription.stripe_subscription=stripe_subscription.id

    subscription.save()
```

can anyone helps out plz to get people to enter their card through invoices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating Sources, those are considered legacy, don't use them.

You need to create a PaymentMethod instead. The way to do that is you use Stripe.js and the Stripe hosted UI "Elements" that allows a customer to enter their card details (in a PCI compliant, Stripe hosted iframe input field) ([by following Step 3 here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-collect-card-details)) and you can [create a PaymentMethod out of that](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method).

Then, you send that PaymentMethod to your server, attach it to the Customer and also pass it as the `default_payment_method` when you create the Subscription.